# Logging EF queries with IDbCommandInterceptor _AND_ attached debugger

Tags: c#, entity-framework, debugging

I'm using `IDbCommandInterceptor` implementation to trace all sql queries executed by EF into the file. Basically it works fine except of one thing that troubles me. When i debug my code and watch some entity in one of the debugger windows, EF may require to fetch additional data from db - which is resulting in execution of sql command that is also intercepted by `IDbCommandInterceptor` and is also processed by logger engine. In fact, it leads to tons of log records within the file which aren't naturally produced by logic in my code, but by my interactions with visual studio IDE in debugger mode. So I want to figure out how to prevent this from happening.

I know about `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`, but it doesn't really help in my situation, because i need to detect *actual* debug mode. By this i mean that the code execution is *actually* stopped by debugger by use of some sort of breakpoint mechanic.

Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

In short you cannot do that, nor should you do that this way. You might want to try [Debugger.CurrentMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/envdte.debugger.currentmode.aspx) (note, it's not System.Diagnostics.Debugger, but another one from EnvDte.dll for Visual Studio automation tasks), but in your case even this won't help (and is ugly solution anyway).

But if you have debugger attached, why log anything to file at all? If you need that file for debugging, but you don't want to bloat your normal query log, just log to special "debug" log file instead if debugger is attached. All in all, you will have to find another way to handle your problem, or just live with that :)

Comment: I don't care about bloating of log file, but i care about finding relevant information in it. Sometimes i need to check sql queries even when debugging my code - that's why i don't want to disable tracing completely while debugger is attached. In my opinion, it is weird that there is no another property in framework like Debugger.IsSteppingThru.

Comment: Well I develope software for years and never needed such property, nor do I need now :) Probably it's just not possible to implement, after all at the moment when your code is executed - debugger is not at break point and behaves as usual (so, just attached).